# SQL With Joins and Pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I spent more than 6 hours today trying to figure this SQL solution to no avail. Honestly, I figured it out after some searches that I had to use the PIVOT instruction (Never saw it before) to get what I´m after, and since then I´ve trying to figure out this command when used with join commands. I´m not that smart per see.

This is what I´m trying to do:

I have these tables (I´m showing the ones I believe are relevant for this question since there a few other INNER JOINS referencing other tables):

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

And this query:

```
SELECT [Easytool_data].[dbo].[estoque].[id] AS ID
      ,[Easytool_data].[dbo].[estoque].[barras] AS PartNumber
      ,[Easytool_data].[dbo].[estoque].[codigo] AS Codigo
      ,[Easytool_data].[dbo].[estoque].[descricao] AS Descricao
      ,[Easytool_data].[dbo].[estoque].[um] AS Unidade
      ,[Easytool_data].[dbo].[familias].[Descricao] AS Familia
      ,[Easytool_data].[dbo].[estoque].[fabricante] AS Fabricante
      ,[Easytool_data].[dbo].[estoque].[modelo] AS Modelo
      ,[Easytool_data].[dbo].[estoque].[armazenagem] AS Local
      ,[Easytool_data].[dbo].[status].[Descricao] AS Situacao
      ,[Easytool_data].[dbo].[estoque].[custo] AS Preco
      ,[Easytool_data].[dbo].[estoque].[sd_atual] AS Saldo
      ,[Easytool_data].[dbo].[local_estoque].[descricao] AS Estoque
      ,[Easytool_data].[dbo].[local_estocado].[quantidade] AS Quantidade

FROM [Easytool_data].[dbo].[estoque] 

INNER JOIN [Easytool_data].[dbo].[familias]       
ON [Easytool_data].[dbo].[estoque].[id_familia] = [Easytool_data].[dbo].[familias].[Id]
INNER JOIN [Easytool_data].[dbo].[status]
ON [Easytool_data].[dbo].[estoque].[id_status] = [Easytool_data].[dbo].[status].[Id]
INNER JOIN [Easytool_data].[dbo].[local_estocado]
ON [Easytool_data].[dbo].[estoque].[id] = [Easytool_data].[dbo].[local_estocado].[id_estoque]
INNER JOIN [Easytool_data].[dbo].[local_estoque]
ON [Easytool_data].[dbo].[local_estocado].[id_local_estoque] = [Easytool_data].[dbo].[local_estoque].[id]

WHERE  [Easytool_data].[dbo].[estoque].[id] = 3954
```

Which returns this:

```
ID     | PartNumber | Codigo    | Descricao   | Unidade | Familia   | Fabricante | Modelo | Local     | Situacao | Preco | Saldo | Estoque     | Quantidade
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
3954   | OSPÇ0024   |  OSPÇ0024 | PINÇA ER 25 | UNIDADE | PINÇA     | SANDVIK    | NULL   | PI 01-D-2 | ATIVO    | 25    | 2     | CENTRAL     | 1
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
3954   | OSPÇ0024   |  OSPÇ0024 | PINÇA ER 25 | UNIDADE | PINÇA     | SANDVIK    | NULL   | PI 01-D-2 | ATIVO    | 25    | 2     | ROTATIVO 0  | 0
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
3954   | OSPÇ0024   |  OSPÇ0024 | PINÇA ER 25 | UNIDADE | PINÇA     | SANDVIK    | NULL   | PI 01-D-2 | ATIVO    | 25    | 2     | REFORMA  0  | 0
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
3954   | OSPÇ0024   |  OSPÇ0024 | PINÇA ER 25 | UNIDADE | PINÇA     | SANDVIK    | NULL   | PI 01-D-2 | ATIVO    | 25    | 2     | EMPRÉSTIMO  | 1
```

I want it to return this:

```
ID     | PartNumber |   Codigo  | Descricao   | Unidade |   Familia | Fabricante | Modelo | Local     | Situacao | Preco | Saldo | Estoque | Quantidade | Estoque    | Quantidade | Estoque   | Quantidade | Estoque    | Quantidade
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
3954   |OSPÇ0024   |  OSPÇ0024  | PINÇA ER 25 | UNIDADE | PINÇA     | SANDVIK    | NULL   | PI 01-D-2 | ATIVO    | 25    | 2     | CENTRAL | 1          | ROTATIVO 0 | 0          | REFORMA 0 | 0          | EMPRÉSTIMO | 1
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I´ve learned very recently that PIVOT can be used to accomplish this, but I´m totally lost about how to use it with several INNER JOIN commands like the one in my query. I´ve tried it in several different ways and always get an error.

Can anybody give me an example about how I could achieve what I´m after using a query similar to mine?

I´ve searched the board and all examples I found were way too complex or way to simple compared to my query. I´m not lazy and I´m willing to put my best efforts in learning this, but it seems out of reach for now.

If someone could shed some light here I´d be very thankful,

Thank you
Daniel

Comment: PIVOT is used for aggregated values

Comment: If you would use table aliases your syntax would be a lot less. Put this`[Easytool_data].[dbo].[estoque] esto` allows you to change references else where like `[Easytool_data].[dbo].[estoque].[id] AS ID`  to `esto.id AS ID`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pivoting horizontally using just SQL is usually about using a descriptive, previously vertical column; the same you use for the CASE expression, as a column name.
Like so:

```
WITH initial_query_output (
  ID
, PartNumber
, Codigo
, Descricao
, Unidade
, Familia
, Fabricante
, Modelo
, Local
, Situacao
, Preco
, Saldo
, Estoque
, Quantidade
) AS (
          SELECT 3954,'OSPÇ002','OSPÇ00','PINÇA ER 2','UNIDAD','PINÇ','SANDVI','NUL','PI 01-D-','ATIV',25,2,'CENTRAL'    ,1
UNION ALL SELECT 3954,'OSPÇ002','OSPÇ00','PINÇA ER 2','UNIDAD','PINÇ','SANDVI','NUL','PI 01-D-','ATIV',25,2,'ROTATIVO 0' ,0
UNION ALL SELECT 3954,'OSPÇ002','OSPÇ00','PINÇA ER 2','UNIDAD','PINÇ','SANDVI','NUL','PI 01-D-','ATIV',25,2,'REFORMA  0' ,0
UNION ALL SELECT 3954,'OSPÇ002','OSPÇ00','PINÇA ER 2','UNIDAD','PINÇ','SANDVI','NUL','PI 01-D-','ATIV',25,2,'EMPRÉSTIMO' ,1
)
SELECT
  ID
, PartNumber
, Codigo
, Descricao
, Unidade
, Familia
, Fabricante
, Modelo
, Local
, Situacao
, Preco
, Saldo
, SUM(CASE Estoque WHEN 'CENTRAL'    THEN Quantidade END) AS "CENTRAL"   
, SUM(CASE Estoque WHEN 'ROTATIVO 0' THEN Quantidade END) AS "ROTATIVO 0"
, SUM(CASE Estoque WHEN 'REFORMA  0' THEN Quantidade END) AS "REFORMA  0"
, SUM(CASE Estoque WHEN 'EMPRÉSTIMO' THEN Quantidade END) AS "EMPRÉSTIMO"
FROM initial_query_output
GROUP BY
  ID
, PartNumber
, Codigo
, Descricao
, Unidade
, Familia
, Fabricante
, Modelo
, Local
, Situacao
, Preco
, Saldo
;

ID   |PartNumber|Codigo|Descricao |Unidade|Familia|Fabricante|Modelo|Local   |Situacao|Preco|Saldo|CENTRAL|ROTATIVO 0|REFORMA  0|EMPRÉSTIMO
3,954|OSPÇ002   |OSPÇ00|PINÇA ER 2|UNIDAD |PINÇ   |SANDVI    |NUL   |PI 01-D-|ATIV    |   25|    2|      1|         0|         0|         1
```

Comment: This one seems even better! Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

This should work if you replace the fullselect, Common Table Expression that I called `initial_query_output` by your query above:

```
WITH initial_query_output (
  ID
, PartNumber
, Codigo
, Descricao
, Unidade
, Familia
, Fabricante
, Modelo
, Local
, Situacao
, Preco
, Saldo
, Estoque
, Quantidade
) AS (
-- replace with your initial query from here
          SELECT 3954,'OSPÇ002','OSPÇ00','PINÇA ER 2','UNIDAD','PINÇ','SANDVI','NUL','PI 01-D-','ATIV',25,2,'CENTRAL'    ,1
UNION ALL SELECT 3954,'OSPÇ002','OSPÇ00','PINÇA ER 2','UNIDAD','PINÇ','SANDVI','NUL','PI 01-D-','ATIV',25,2,'ROTATIVO 0' ,0
UNION ALL SELECT 3954,'OSPÇ002','OSPÇ00','PINÇA ER 2','UNIDAD','PINÇ','SANDVI','NUL','PI 01-D-','ATIV',25,2,'REFORMA  0' ,0
UNION ALL SELECT 3954,'OSPÇ002','OSPÇ00','PINÇA ER 2','UNIDAD','PINÇ','SANDVI','NUL','PI 01-D-','ATIV',25,2,'EMPRÉSTIMO' ,1
-- replace with your initial query until here
)
SELECT
  ID
, PartNumber
, Codigo
, Descricao
, Unidade
, Familia
, Fabricante
, Modelo
, Local
, Situacao
, Preco
, Saldo
, MAX(CASE Estoque WHEN 'CENTRAL'    THEN Estoque    END) AS Estoque1
, MAX(CASE Estoque WHEN 'CENTRAL'    THEN Quantidade END) AS Quantidade1
, MAX(CASE Estoque WHEN 'ROTATIVO 0' THEN Estoque    END) AS Estoque2
, MAX(CASE Estoque WHEN 'ROTATIVO 0' THEN Quantidade END) AS Quantidade2
, MAX(CASE Estoque WHEN 'REFORMA  0' THEN Estoque    END) AS Estoque3
, MAX(CASE Estoque WHEN 'REFORMA  0' THEN Quantidade END) AS Quantidade3
, MAX(CASE Estoque WHEN 'EMPRÉSTIMO' THEN Estoque    END) AS Estoque4
, MAX(CASE Estoque WHEN 'EMPRÉSTIMO' THEN Quantidade END) AS Quantidade4
FROM initial_query_output
GROUP BY
  ID
, PartNumber
, Codigo
, Descricao
, Unidade
, Familia
, Fabricante
, Modelo
, Local
, Situacao
, Preco
, Saldo

ID   |PartNumber|Codigo|Descricao |Unidade|Familia|Fabricante|Modelo|Local   |Situacao|Preco|Saldo|Estoque1|Quantidade1|Estoque2  |Quantidade2|Estoque3  |Quantidade3|Estoque4  |Quantidade4
3,954|OSPÇ002   |OSPÇ00|PINÇA ER 2|UNIDAD |PINÇ   |SANDVI    |NUL   |PI 01-D-|ATIV    |   25|    2|CENTRAL |          1|ROTATIVO 0|          0|REFORMA  0|          0|EMPRÉSTIMO|          1
```

Comment: It worked! I´ll try now to remove the extra columns and make the Qty to appear below the rows 'CENTRAL', 'REFORMA'.... Not sure yet if I´ll be able to do it but it is worth a try! Thank you @marcothesane

Comment: I'll post a second answer. This is what I would have done from the start. Wait a few seconds ...

Answer (score 0):

I assume the first subquery returns one row only by each `[Easytool_data].[dbo].[estoque].[id]`, If not you must GRUP BY every field in the subquery.

```
WITH Cmd As
(
    SELECT [Easytool_data].[dbo].[estoque].[id] AS ID
          ,[Easytool_data].[dbo].[estoque].[barras] AS PartNumber
          ,[Easytool_data].[dbo].[estoque].[codigo] AS Codigo
          ,[Easytool_data].[dbo].[estoque].[descricao] AS Descricao
          ,[Easytool_data].[dbo].[estoque].[um] AS Unidade
          ,[Easytool_data].[dbo].[familias].[Descricao] AS Familia
          ,[Easytool_data].[dbo].[estoque].[fabricante] AS Fabricante
          ,[Easytool_data].[dbo].[estoque].[modelo] AS Modelo
          ,[Easytool_data].[dbo].[estoque].[armazenagem] AS Local
          ,[Easytool_data].[dbo].[status].[Descricao] AS Situacao
          ,[Easytool_data].[dbo].[estoque].[custo] AS Preco
          ,[Easytool_data].[dbo].[estoque].[sd_atual] AS Saldo
    FROM [Easytool_data].[dbo].[estoque] 
    INNER JOIN [Easytool_data].[dbo].[familias]       
    ON [Easytool_data].[dbo].[estoque].[id_familia] = [Easytool_data].[dbo].[familias].[Id]
    INNER JOIN [Easytool_data].[dbo].[status]
    ON [Easytool_data].[dbo].[estoque].[id_status] = [Easytool_data].[dbo].[status].[Id]
    WHERE  [Easytool_data].[dbo].[estoque].[id] = 3954
)
SELECT ID, PartNumber, Codigo, Descricao, Unidade, Familia, Fabricante, Modelo
       , Local, Situacao, Preco, Saldo,
       CASE WHEN [Easytool_data].[dbo].[local_estoque].[descricao] = 'CENTRAL' 
            THEN [Easytool_data].[dbo].[local_estocado].[quantidade]
            ELSE 0 END AS CENTRAL, 
       CASE WHEN [Easytool_data].[dbo].[local_estoque].[descricao] = 'ROTATIVO' 
            THEN [Easytool_data].[dbo].[local_estocado].[quantidade]
            ELSE 0 END AS ROTATIVO, 
       CASE WHEN [Easytool_data].[dbo].[local_estoque].[descricao] = 'REFORMA' 
            THEN [Easytool_data].[dbo].[local_estocado].[quantidade]
            ELSE 0 END AS REFORMA, 
       CASE WHEN [Easytool_data].[dbo].[local_estoque].[descricao] = 'EMPRÉSTIMO' 
            THEN [Easytool_data].[dbo].[local_estocado].[quantidade]
            ELSE 0 END AS EMPReSTIMO 
FROM Cmd
    INNER JOIN [Easytool_data].[dbo].[local_estoque]
    ON Cmd.[id_local_estoque] = [Easytool_data].[dbo].[local_estoque].[id];
    INNER JOIN [Easytool_data].[dbo].[local_estocado]
    ON [Easytool_data].[dbo].[local_estocado].[id_estoque] = Cmd.Id;
```

Comment: Try it now.   . l

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm a bit tired, 3 tables for cte query, 2 more for second subquery

Comment: I tried with your latest code and I get these errors: http://imgur.com/a/sEeOR - I changed the code a bit to be like this: https://codeshare.io/aYL6mY - Now I get no errors but the data is also not retrieved. Nothing is returned. I checked all JOINS and they make sense. This is the database backup: http://www.filedropper.com/easytoolpivot (30mb) - Do you see any obvious mistake in my code?